# How to custom sort Laravel Collection or Model?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections, eloquent

I have a collection like the following:

```
[
 user => [
       orders => [
          [1, product1, qty, Pending], //Pending is status
          [2, product2, qty, Processing],
          [3, product3, qty, Shipping],
          [4, product1, qty, Delivered],
          [5, product2, qty, Rejected],
       ],
      comments => [...],
      ...
    ]
]
```

Now I can get orders & sort them by as `$user->orders->sortBy('status')` or `$user->orders->sortByDesc('status')`

If I sort using `sortBy()` this places Delivered orders first & if sort using `sortByDesc()` this place Shipping first.

## but I want to sort (status) by Processing, Shipping, Delivered, Rejected, Pending

in this order, How can I do that (in most efficient Laravelish way)?

Same thing applies when retrieving the collection using `User::orderBy('...')->find($id)` 
How can I do custom sort in this case too?